# Is it considered a good practice to create and dispatch custom Javascript events?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, browser

My web application uses `document.createEvent` and `event.initEvent` to create custom events of the generic type `Event`.

I wonder whether this is considered good practice. On the hand side, this way I can make use of the DOM event system that is already there and do not have to invent and implement my own; on the other hand this may lead to name clashes in case future standardised event models define an event type with the name I have chosen. (Or is it possible to namespace event types?)

I am asking because I have just learnt by browsing stackoverflow that putting custom properties on DOM objects or builtin Javascript objects is considered bad practise.

**EDIT**
I think I have found something:
http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-CustomEvent

So let me rephrase my question: Am I understanding the quoted section correctly in that it is advised to actually use a `CustomEvent` inside a web application?

**ADDED WARNING**
I have just noticed that `CustomEvent` is not supported in Firefox versions before 6. It is supported in current Webkit-based browsers, though.

Comment: You mean, what are the pitfalls or most appropriate way of creating custom events? Because using your own events would be project-specific, I would think.

Comment: Yes, they will be project-specific but the underlying code may be reused later. So I don't want to implement something that is frowned upon, which has made me wondering whether I should hook into the DOM event model at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to create something and make it as namespace-proof as you can, you can do what Webkit and Mozilla do and add a name-moniker to the beginning of all of your event names. Like:

```
_marc_trap_door_shut
_marc_trap_door_open
_marc_trap_door_ajar
... etc ...
```